# Não consigo extrair dados de um site ou arquivo .txt

Tags: php, regex

Olá, gostaria de extrair alguns dados de um site ou mesmo de um bloco de notas exemplo

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/rq9vXKI.jpg" group-title="FILMES",Mulher-Maravilha (2017)
http://cdnv4.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCFServer1/ondemand/MLHRMRVLHA.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/ftEGyMy.jpg" group-title="FILMES",Guardiões da Galáxia Vol. 2 (2017)
http://cdnv4.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCFServer1/ondemand/GRDOESDGLXIAVL2.mp4
```

Gostaria de retirar

```
"https://i.imgur.com/rq9vXKI.jpg", Mulher-Maravilha e http://cdnv4.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCFServer1/ondemand/MLHRMRVLHA.mp4

"https://i.imgur.com/ftEGyMy.jpg", Guardiões da Galáxia e http://cdnv4.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCFServer1/ondemand/GRDOESDGLXIAVL2.mp4
```

E enviar isso para um DB separado e em ordem, ja tentei usar expressão regular, mas não consigo, isso seria um metodo para facilitar para enviar filmes para o site, envia uma lista e ele ja separa com o seu link a sua imagem e seu devido nome, por favor alguem me ajuda!!!
Não me importa se eu estiver extraindo de um arquivo um site, só q separe tudo corretamente e jogue tudo dentro do db, agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar expressão regular ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)), um exemplo que funcionaria com o seu .txt:

```
#tvg-logo="(https?://[^\s]+)"(\s+|)group-title="\w+",([\s\S]+?)(https?://[^\s]+)#
```

A explicação da regex:

- `tvg-logo="(https?://[^\s]+)"` vai pegar a foto/imagem/thumb, o `(\s+|)` logo após (antes do group) é para checar espaços, tendo uma separação ou mais por espaço ou nenhum
- `group-title="\w+",` vai pegar qualquer coisa como `group-title="FILMES",` ou `group-title="SERIES",`
- `([\s\S]+?)` vai pegar tudo que vier depois da virgula até encontrar o link http
- `https?` vai procurar por ocorrencias com http ou https
- `(https?://[^\s]+)` vai pegar o link inteiro

Então o script php ficaria assim:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');

$regex = '#tvg-logo="(https?://[^\s]+)"(\s+|)group-title="\w+",([\s\S]+?)(https?://[^\s]+)#';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $txt, $output)) {

    array_shift($output);

    $j = count($output[0]);

    echo '------------------', PHP_EOL;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {

        $titulo = trim($output[2][$i]); //Pega o titulo

        $imagem = $output[0][$i]; //Pega a imagem

        $url = $output[3][$i]; //Pega a url

        echo 'Titulo: ', $titulo, '<br>';
        echo 'imagem: ', $imagem, '<br>';
        echo 'url: ', $url, '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Um exemplo para teste (teste online: https://repl.it/@inphinit/Pegar-videos-no-txt):

```
$txt = '
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/rq9vXKI.jpg" group-title="FILMES",Mulher-Maravilha (2017)
http://cdnv4.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCFServer1/ondemand/MLHRMRVLHA.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/ftEGyMy.jpg" group-title="FILMES",Guardiões da Galáxia Vol. 2 (2017)
http://cdnv4.ec.cx/RedeCanais/RedeCanais/RCFServer1/ondemand/GRDOESDGLXIAVL2.mp4
';

$regex = '#tvg-logo="(https?://[^\s]+)"(\s+|)group-title="\w+",([\s\S]+?)(https?://[^\s]+)#';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $txt, $output)) {

    array_shift($output);

    $j = count($output[0]);

    echo '------------------', PHP_EOL;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {

        $titulo = trim($output[2][$i]); //Pega o titulo

        $imagem = $output[0][$i]; //Pega a imagem

        $url = $output[3][$i]; //Pega a url

        echo 'Titulo: ', $titulo, PHP_EOL;
        echo 'imagem: ', $imagem, PHP_EOL;
        echo 'url: ', $url, PHP_EOL;
        echo '------------------', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ola amigo muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, mas você poderia me ajudar incrementar no código para pegar a imagem ex: https://i.imgur.com/rq9vXKI.jpg que esta dentro do tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/rq9vXKI.jpg", eu tentei ir fazendo pelo caminho que você estava usando ex: tvg-logo="\w+" para pegar tudo do tvg logo com ([\s\S]+?) só que não consigo já tentei ir no regexpal e parece que não consigo chegar a nada, alem de você poder ajuda a terminar esse código você poderia me indicar algum site ou videos para eu entender essa parte do PHP? é foda, pois essa parte parece ser muito interessante.

Comment: @CaioSalchesttes a perdão, falha minha, esqueci da thumb, um minuto!

Comment: @CaioSalchesttes atualizei a resposta, testa e me diz, se quiser testar em https://repl.it/@inphinit/Pegar-videos-no-txt também.